# What does 폭탄마냥 means?

Tags: vocabulary

To be exact 폭탄마냥 as in 폭탄마냥 보고 있다.
But 폭탄 means bomb, so i assume it is probably some kind of idiom and not literally means bomb in that context?

Edit: i attached 2 example of '...폭탄마냥 보고 있다.'
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CAh9.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXkD8.jpg)

Comment: (1) For your *incomplete* sentence, 마냥 means **처럼**. (2) The context is necessary because there are no idioms related to 폭탄. (3) "... 폭탄 보듯이 보고 있다." will be a better sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned that 마냥 means 처럼; I will correct your example sentences as the following:

> **A.** 왜 도시락을 폭탄**처럼** 보고 있지?
>
> **B.** 작은 헛기침 소리 외엔 별다른 말을 하지 않는 의사를 인찬은 시한 폭탄**처럼** 보고 있었다. 언제 의사의 입에서 자신이 예상하는 말이 튀어나올지, 기다리는 심장이 두근거림을 참지 못하고 토해내고 있었다.

Sentence **A** literally means "Why (are you / is he / is she / are they / am I) seeing the lunch (box) as a bomb?" I do not know the background of your example, but it is good to know the history of Korea. This is a quotation from [an article on The Korea Times](http://www.koreatimes.co.kr/www/news/biz/2013/08/367_121182.html):

> The other is Yun Bong-gil who in 1932 staged an attack with **a bomb disguised as a lunch box** at a Japanese army celebration of Emperor Hirohito’s birthday in Shanghai, killing several high-ranking Japanese military figures.

Most Koreans living in Korea have heard about the lunch box bomb (도시락 폭탄), so this figure of speech is highly effective. Sentence A may not closely relate to the history nonetheless. Interpret the words considering the context.

Sentences in **B** indicate that 인찬 is looking at the doctor as if the doctor were a time bomb because the doctor is keeping silent. 인찬 is nervous because he thinks the doctor is going to say something *big* to him *suddenly* like a time bomb awaiting for the time. Now, use your imagination to understand this figure of speech.